# Get list of kafka consumers for a specific topic

Tags: apache-kafka

We have a distributed, multi region, multi zone Kafka cluster. We are the platform owners and maintain and administer the cluster. There are applications which utilize our platform for their upstream/downstream data.
Now, how can we list down the consumers which are reading a specific topic?
So far I understand that, we can list all consumer groups and then describe them and thereafter search for topics in that.
Is there any simpler or other available solutions out there?

Answer (score 0):

Without auditing/tracing via authorization plugins, describing each group is the best you can do out of the box.

Related blog that covers using Zipkin for client tracing - https://www.confluent.io/blog/importance-of-distributed-tracing-for-apache-kafka-based-applications/

In several jobs, I've seen several gatekeeping processes such as OpenPolicyAgent, Apache Ranger (for LDAP integration), internal web onboarding portals, etc. that were required for getting access to any Kafka topic.